# Inherited function will read data member of parent class or child class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

```
class A{
    int var;
public:
    virtual void foo(); // sets var
    void bar(); // reads var and displays value
};

class B : public A{
    int var;
public:
    void foo();
};

void A::bar(){
    printf("%d",var);
}

void B::foo(){
    var = 42;
}

void func(){
    B myObj;
    myObj.foo();
    myObj.bar();
}

class A2{
    virtual void foo(); // sets var
public:
    int var;
    void bar(); // read var and displays value
};

class B2 : public A2{
public:
    void foo();
};
```

1. Upon a call to `foo` in `func` will foo set `A::var` or `B::var`?
2. And in call to `bar` in `func` will `bar` read `A::var` or `B::var`?
3. Do I need to declare `var` as a data member in `A` if no instance of `A` will ever be created?
4. Will the class declarations `A2` and `B2` work to the same effect as `A` and `B`?

Comment: Have you tried simply running the code to find out? It seems to me as if you could just run and try this?

Comment: I want to understand why something works and why something doesn't. Of course I'll run it too.

Comment: `func` won't compile: `myObj.foo` is private.

Comment: Sorry, fixed that. @aschepler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding 1. and 2. There's an error since foo is not visible (and `A::foo` hasn't a body):

```
class B : public A{
    int var;
    void foo();
};
```

anyway since you're not calling it through a pointer/reference

```
void func(){
  B myObj;
  myObj.foo(); // No polymorphic behavior here, B::foo is called
  myObj.bar(); // the same, but A::bar is called since B hasn't one
}
```

Regarding 3. and 4. if both base and derived class have a variable with the same name, the derived's one hides the name of the base class and every access through a derived object will result in the derived one being set/called (unless explicitly doing `base::var`). If only one has it, it's fine and they will both call the same version (provided it's visible/accessible). In your example above:

```
void A::bar(){
   std::cout << var; // This will output an uninitialized A::var!
}

void B::foo(){
   var = 42; // B's var hides A's var so this only sets the derived one's
}
```

Edit: in the case for `A2` and `B2` there's only one instance of `A2::var` and every access to it, even from a derived class, will refer to the base one, e.g.

```
class A2{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
public:
    int var;
    void bar() {
        std::cout << var; // Will correctly output 42
    }
};

class B2 : public A2{
public:
    void foo() {
        var = 42; // Sets the common A2::var variable
    };
};

void func2(){
    B2 myObj;
    myObj.foo();
    myObj.bar();
}
```

Take a look and study the following: <kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/M1AwY7)</kbd>

Comment: Can you please elaborate more about `A2` and `B2`?

Comment: @tMJ I just did, take a look at the example I attached. It should be explicative of what's happening.

Comment: Thanks, makes it a lot clearer! I have another question though, can I declare a method in the parent class (I am sure no instances of the parent class would be ever created) and define it in the child class. What is this technique called.

Comment: @tMJ Unless you mark the base method as [pure virtual](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/126-pure-virtual-functions-abstract-base-classes-and-interface-classes/) (that means "every derived class must implement this") you need to define it in the base class as well.

Answer (score 1):

After you fixed the private problem mentioned in the comment, and also provided an implementation for A::foo to avoid the "undefined vtable" error, then you'll see that you're calling B::foo which leaves A::var alone, but bar prints out A::var.

It's rather goofy to use the same variable name in a derived class, but I'll bear it in mind for my future obfuscation requirements.

A2 and B2 look less surreal.

Answer (score 1):

> Upon a call to foo in func will foo set A::var or B::var?

foo will set B::var

> And in call to bar in func will bar read A::var or B::var?

bar in func() will return A::var, which will be zero or undefined

> Do I need to declare var as a data member in A if no instance of A
>   will ever be created?

Yes, since it's the void A::bar() that return the variable.

> Will the class declarations A2 and B2 work to the same effect as A and
>   B?

No, A2::bar and B2::bar will return the same var (42).

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Upon a call to foo in func will foo set A::var or B::var?

`foo()` is virtual, and the dynamic (and indeed static) type of `myObj` is `B`, so it will be `B::foo()` that gets called, setting `B::var`.

Note that in this case the `virtual` has no effect, as you're not using polymorphism.

> 2. And in call to bar in func will bar read A::var or B::var?

It will read `A::var`.

> 3. Do I need to declare var as a data member in A if no instance of A will ever be created?

You'd need to make `A::bar()` virtual I would think, or have `B::foo()` call `A::foo()` at some point to set the base member variable.

> 4. Will the class declarations A2 and B2 work to the same effect as A and B?

In what way do you expect them to be different?